# Node.js->fs module keeps refreshing html page

Tags: node.js, file, electron

I use Electron framework and have two places to store info either sessionStorage or files, sessionStorage does not refresh the page, however it is limited in size, while fs module is perfect for my data size but it keeps refreshing the page whenever I use writeFileSync.

Is there a way to obtain fast, unlimited way of storing data which will not refresh the page after access?

Comment: Post your code. Please complete the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read ["How to Ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). If possible you should provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.